# Get current displayed text in textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a textView with a max linenumber. When the text extends the max linenumber, I want to show a toggle button to expand the text.

Is there any way to see if the text extends the max linenumbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Textwatcher` to corresponding textview.in `onTextchange()` you have to count the length of text.if it cross your limit you may show toggle button.I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below condition:

```
if(textview.getLineCount()==textview.getMaxLines()){
        //show the toggle button
 }
```